# can i avoid comma in explode in my php function?

Tags: php, arrays, text-files, explode

I have the following function. In the PI-Detail-ASXX.txt file the data has delimiter as "**~** ". I am using following function to explode the symbol but it removes **","** as well.

```
function checkFeatures($productID,$count)
{
$fd = fopen('PI-Detail-ASXX.txt', 'r');
$fline = 0;

while ( ( $frow = fgetcsv($fd) ) !== false ) {
    if ($fline <=0 ) {
        // headings, so continue/ignore this iteration:
        $fline++;
        continue;
        }
    //for lines other than headers
   if($fline >0){
   $contents = explode("~", $frow[0]);
   print_r($contents);
   $fline++;
   }
 }
}
```

For example if you have this data in txt file. My function skips the first header line, reads the second line but cuts the array at to **deploy,** and prints only 3 array elements because of the comma i believe. The third line is printed correctly with 5 array elements. Does anyone know how to not let that happen.

```
IMSKU~AttributeID~Value~Unit~StoredValue~StoredUnit  
1000001~7332~McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention for Desktops safeguards your business against complex security threats that may otherwise be unintentionally introduced or allowed by desktops and laptops. Host Intrusion Prevention for Desktops is easy to deploy, configure, and manage.~~~  
1000001~7343~May 2013~~~  
1000001~7344~McAfee~~0.00~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading the file with `fgetcsv()` which breaks on a comma by default. Thereafter you're exploding on `~`. You could add an extra paramter to `fgetcsv()` and it'll break on the `~` directly into an array and no need to explode the string afterwards.

This should give you the idea, but I haven't tested it.

```
function checkFeatures($productID,$count)
{
    $fd = fopen('PI-Detail-ASXX.txt', 'r');
    $fheader = fgets($fd); // read and discard header first

    while ( ( $frow = fgetcsv($fd,0,'~') ) !== false ) {
        print_r($frow);
    }
    fclose($fd);
}
```

[PHP Reference for fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: It worked perfectly. Better option than the explode.